# Python - pad 0s in a list of strings of numbers (not integers) - ZFILL

Tags: python

I'm learning python with a side-project.

Stuck on this for ~30 minutes now.  How do I pad a 0 on a string of numbers so my output will always be 2 digits?  The strings hitting this list will always be two digits.  I would rather keep this a string instead of an integer.

```
moo = ['06', '07', '8', '9', '12']
moo = str(moo).zfill(2)
print(moo)
```

I'm returning the same thing..

```
['06', '07', '8', '9', '12']
```

desired output:

```
['06, '07', '08', '09, '12']
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`moo` is a list of strings, so you can't directly use the `str.zfill` method on it.

You can use list comprehension to do it instead:

```
moo = [i.zfill(2) for i in moo]
```

`moo` would then become:

```
['06', '07', '08', '09', '12']
```

Answer (score 1):

With `str(moo)` you are converting your list to a string `"['06', '07', '8', '9', '12']"`, thus `zfill(2)` will not change anything, because the string is already 28 characters wide.

Instead you should iterate each list item:

```
moo = ['06', '07', '8', '9', '12']
for idx, item in enumerate(moo):
    moo[idx] = item.zfill(2)
print(moo)
```

Or use a list comprehension:

```
moo = ['06', '07', '8', '9', '12']
moo = [item.zfill(2) for item in moo]
print(moo)
```

Output:

```
['06', '07', '08', '09', '12']
```

Answer (score 1):

The zfill function should be applied to every digit. You could 
Try This

```
moo = ['06', '07', '8', '9', '12']                                              
moo = [str(x).zfill(2) for x in moo]                                            
print(moo)
```